# Appcelerator Titanium upload to google drive - Rest API in Javascript - Error 404

Tags: javascript, http, appcelerator, google-drive-api

Im trying to upload an image to google drive using appcelerator titanium.
I have got OAuth and i have an access_token which is valid.

Unfortunately when i try and upload the image i get a 404 http error.

```
function Upload(blob){
Titanium.API.info(googleAuth.getAccessToken());
const boundary = '-------314159265358979323846';
const delimiter = "\r\n--" + boundary + "\r\n";
const close_delim = "\r\n--" + boundary + "--";

var request = Ti.Network.createHTTPClient({

onload : function(e) {

alert(this.requestText); },

    onerror : function(e) {
    Titanium.UI.createAlertDialog({
    title : 'Error',
    message : 'unable to upload' + JSON.stringify(e)
    }).show();
    },
    timeout : 60000

});

var metadata = {
    'title' : "image1.png",
    'mimeType': 'application/json',
};

var mediaRequestBody = 
 delimiter +
    'Content-Type: application/json\r\n\r\n' +
    JSON.stringify(metadata) +
    delimiter +
    blob +
    close_delim;

    var uploadRequest = {
    'headers': {
      'Content-Type': 'multipart/mixed; boundary="' + boundary + '"',
      'access_token' : googleAuth.getAccessToken()
    },
    'body': mediaRequestBody};



var url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drivev2/files?uploadType=multipart';
request.open("POST", url);
request.send(uploadRequest);
```

}

The 'Blob' i pass through is retrieved by doing:

```
var f = Titanium.Filesystem.getFile(Titanium.Filesystem.applicationDataDirectory,filename);
f.write(image);
var url = f.nativePath;
var blob = f.read();
```

I think close but it's probably my http request.

Thanks.!

[This is the error i get jsonified](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dfPMT.png)

Comment: wild guess add an extra \r\n at the very end of uploadRequest.  I seam to remember it giving me a hard time when I did this in C#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was also facing the same type of issue sometime back and following is how I was able to solve it.

*Considering I have :*

- `blob` of the image which I have to upload.
- **Access token** required for the google api's.
- Scope which I used is :

  1. https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive
  2. https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.appdata
  3. https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file

**Step 1:** Convert blob image to base64 encoded string.

```
var base64image = Ti.Utils.base64encode(blobData);
```

**Step 2:** Create the request body to upload image to drive.

```
var reqBody = '--foo_bar_baz\nContent-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8\n\n{"title": "' + myFileName + '"}\n--foo_bar_baz\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\nContent-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n\n' + base64image + '\n--foo_bar_baz--';
```

**Step 3:** Set the necessary headers for the request.

```
client.setRequestHeader('Authorization', "Bearer " + myAccessToken); 
client.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'multipart/related; boundary="foo_bar_baz"' );
```

***The basic snippet :***

```
function upLoadFile(myAccessToken) {
    var base64image = Ti.Utils.base64encode(blobData); //convert blob to base64 encoded string

    var myFileName = "MyImage.png";
    var reqBody = '--foo_bar_baz\nContent-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8\n\n{"title": "' + myFileName + '"}\n--foo_bar_baz\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\nContent-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n\n' + base64image + '\n--foo_bar_baz--';
    var url = "https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v2/files";
    var client = Ti.Network.createHTTPClient({
        onload : function(e) {
            Ti.API.info("Received text: " + this.responseText);
            alert('success');
        },
        onerror : function(e) {
            Ti.API.debug(e.error);
            alert('error');
        },
        timeout : 100000000
    });
    client.open("POST", url);
    client.setRequestHeader('Authorization', "Bearer " + myAccessToken); 
    client.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'multipart/related; boundary="foo_bar_baz"' ); 
    client.send(reqBody);
}
```

P.S : This answer uses [**Drive API v2**](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/), also see Drive docs on [Manage Upload](https://developers.google.com/drive/web/manage-uploads).

*Hope it is helpful.*