# Upload/share videos to youtube in Titanium

Tags: youtube, titanium

I need to share and upload my videos to youtube in Titanium Alloy for both iOS and Android.
Is there any Youtube API available for Titanium ?

Comment: No I dont think their is any Titanium related API for uploading videos to youtube. But you can utilize [Youtube rest API's](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/) for same.

Comment: @turtle There is Javascript APIs available but i think these are browser dependent .How can i utilize them ? can you please suggest me or share some code.

Comment: Well Ajit, I dont have any doc/tutorial but the Youtube Api's are restful. So you can check the doc to integrate it. For using Youtube Api's, I think you will need oAuth token. You can use [this module](https://github.com/ejci/Google-Auth-for-Titanium) to fetch oAuth token and then check Youtube Api's for further progress.

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27269010/3419997) is related to uploading files to google drive; you can check how the coding is done referring the drive's doc.

Comment: Thanks @turtle let me try those

Comment: @turtle : Other than this method , i can use intents to choose video and share in desired apps in android. Is there any way i can have the same functionality in ios?

Comment: You would want to check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17440935/equivalent-to-androids-share-intent-concept-for-iphone-using-titanium).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[this Answer](http://www.oodlestechnologies.com/blogs/Upload%20or%20share%20video%20on%20youtube%20in%20Appcelerator%20Titanium)

will work like charm

Comment: Thanks , but please check the author . I have written that blog.
I was searching for any Titanium methods to do instead.

Comment: @Ajit can you help me adding uploaded video to a specific channel (pre fetched ) by passing in parts or somewhere ?

Comment: Yes you have to add parts to pre-fetched channel and make REST call to upload to a specific channel.Please explain your problem.

Comment: Looks like i have to accept this answer as final one.